# Can both CM and CD servers point to the same MongoDB instance of Sitecore xDB?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-xdb

For my DEV and TEST I have both a CM server and a CD server. I have one SQL instance for DEV and another one for TEST. DEV's CM and CD point to the DEV's SQL instance and TEST's CM and CD point to the TEST's SQL instance.

Will there be any problem if I use MongoDB in the same manner? I want to use only one instance for DEV and one for TEST, where both CM and CD of DEV point to the DEV's MongoDB and both CM and CD of TEST will point to the TEST's MongoDB.

For Example:

#### DEV CM and CD connection string:

```xml
<add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://UserName:Password@mongodbServerDEV/tracking_live" />
```

#### TEST CM and CD connection string:

```xml
<add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://UserName:Password@mongodbServerTEST/tracking_live" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your CM and CD environment need to point to the same Mongo environment. So yes, it is no problem.

Comment: Thank you for the info, is there any blog or document available for understanding more about these infrastructure management for sitecore.

Comment: A good starting point can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/platform/architecture_overview

Answer (score -1):

Technically that should not be a problem. Before using the information/data from Mongodb, just keep in mind that it will contain tracking details of both CM & CD environment.

Comment: Why? His dev and test environment are pointing to different Mongo instances. It's CM and CD that are using the same.

Comment: Well, per [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server), you need to disable writes to xDB on your CM. So your answer is still incorrect for OP's case.

Comment: Well, the question was whether its a problem? Its not. Its just not useful to have CM connected to mongodb.